# Cookie Value shows up as 'Undefined' or 'NaN'

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I am working on an app for keeping track of a card game's score. One "comfort feature" as I like to call it that I would like to add is cookies. After a little research, I ended up with the code shown at the bottom of this post. However when changing the values of the two variables that are stored in the cookie, saving the cookie, and reloading the page, while one variable ends up fine, the other comes out as NaN. When looking in Firefox's debugger, I can confirm that when reading the cookie, which happens in a function when I load the webpage, while the first value saves fine, the second one has a value of 'undefined'. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canasta Scoring</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3c78002abf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body onload="start()" id="content">
    <p class="title">Canasta Scoring</p>
    <div class="table">
        <hr class="blank">
        <div class="p1">
            <input type="text" value="Player One" class="playertitle">
            <hr>
            <div class="bonus1">
                <hr class="blank">
                <p class="cat">Bonus</p>
                <hr class="blank">
                <input type="number" name="bonusone" id="bonusnumone" class="num" placeholder="10000">
                <hr class="blank">
            </div>
            <div class="count1">
                <hr class="blank">
                <p class="cat">Card Count</p>
                <hr class="blank">
                <input type="number" name="countone" id="countnumone" class="num" placeholder="345">
                <hr class="blank">
            </div>
            <button class="submit" id="subone" onclick="addone()">Submit to Total!</button>
            <p class="total" id="totalone">####</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="p2">
            <input type="text" value="Player Two" class="playertitle">
            <div class="bonus2">
                <hr class="blank">
                <p class="cat">Bonus</p>
                <hr class="blank">
                <input type="number" name="bonustwo" id="bonusnumtwo" class="num" placeholder="10000">
                <hr class="blank">
            </div>
            <div class="count2">
                <hr class="blank">
                <p class="cat">Card Count</p>
                <hr class="blank">
                <input type="number" name="counttwo" id="countnumtwo" class="num" placeholder="345">
                <hr class="blank">
            </div>
            <button class="submit" id="subtwo" onclick="addtwo()">Submit to Total!</button>
            <p class="total" id="totaltwo">####</p>
        </div>
        <hr class="blank">
    </div>
    <hr class="blank">
    <div class="resetbefore" id="resetbefore">
        <button class="reset" onclick="ask()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="resetduring" id="resetduring">
        <p class="total">Are You Sure?</p>
        <button class="reset" onclick="reset()">Yes</button>
        <button class="reset" onclick="cancel()">No</button>
    </div>
    <hr class="blank">
    <hr class="blank">
    <div class="modes">
        <button class="color" onclick="dark()"><i class="fa-solid fa-moon fa-6x"></i></button>
        <button class="color" onclick="light()"><i class="fa-solid fa-sun fa-6x"></i></button>
        <button class="color" onclick="normal()"><i class="fa-solid fa-palette fa-6x"></i></button>
        <button class="color" onclick="photo()"><i class="fa-solid fa-diamond fa-6x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <hr class="blank">
    <hr class="blank">
    <p>©2023 David Kolenda</p>
    <p>All Rights Reserved to Copyright Holders</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let onebonus = 0;
let twobonus = 0;
let onecount = 0;
let twocount = 0;
let onetotal = 0;
let twototal = 0;
let oneall = 0;
let twoall = 0;

function start() {
    const cookieValue = document.cookie
    .split("; ")
    .find((row) => row.startsWith("int1="));
    if (cookieValue) {
        const [, value1, value2] = cookieValue.split(/[=;]/);
        onetotal = parseInt(value1);
        twototal = parseInt(value2);
      }
    display()
}

function display() {
    document.getElementById('totalone').innerHTML = onetotal;
    document.getElementById('totaltwo').innerHTML = twototal;
    check()
}

function check() {
    if (onetotal > 5000 && twototal > 5000) {
        if (onetotal > twototal) {
            document.getElementById('totalone').style.color = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
            document.getElementById('totaltwo').style.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('totaltwo').style.color = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
            document.getElementById('totalone').style.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        }
    } else {
        if (onetotal > 5000) {
            document.getElementById('totalone').style.color = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
        } if (twototal > 5000) {
            document.getElementById('totaltwo').style.color = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
        } else {
            console.log('Neither Player Has Won Yet!')
        }
    }
    saveCookie()
}

function addone() {
    onebonus = document.getElementById('bonusnumone').value;
    onecount = document.getElementById('countnumone').value;
    oneall = parseInt(onebonus) + parseInt(onecount);
    onetotal = parseInt(onetotal) + parseInt(oneall);
    oneall = 0;
    onebonus = 0;
    document.getElementById('countnumone').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('bonusnumone').value = 0;
    display()
}


function addtwo() {
    twobonus = document.getElementById('bonusnumtwo').value;
    twocount = document.getElementById('countnumtwo').value;
    twoall = parseInt(twobonus) + parseInt(twocount);
    twototal = parseInt(twototal) + parseInt(twoall);
    twoall = 0;
    twobonus = 0;
    document.getElementById('countnumtwo').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('bonusnumtwo').value = 0;
    display()
}

function dark() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0))';
    document.getElementById('content').style.color = 'white';
    display()
}

function light() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(255, 255, 255))';
    document.getElementById('content').style.color = 'black';
    display()
}

function normal() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(112, 222, 21), rgb(77, 201, 15))';
    document.getElementById('content').style.color = 'black';
    display()
}

function photo() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(background.png)';
    document.getElementById('content').style.color = 'black';
    display()
}

function ask() {
    document.getElementById('resetbefore').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('resetduring').style.display = 'inline';
}

function cancel() {
    document.getElementById('resetbefore').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('resetduring').style.display = 'none';
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById('resetbefore').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('resetduring').style.display = 'none';
    onebonus = 0;
    twobonus = 0;
    onecount = 0;
    twocount = 0;
    onetotal = 0;
    twototal = 0;
    oneall = 0;
    twoall = 0;
    display()
}

function saveCookie() {
    document.cookie = `int1=${onetotal};int2=${twototal}`;
}
```

CSS

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('background.png');
    color: black;
}

.title {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 999;
}

.table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.blank {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.p1 {
    border: 1px #313131 solid;
    display: grid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.p2 {
    border: 1px #313131 solid;
    display: grid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bonus1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.count1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bonus2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.count2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.playertitle {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.playertitle:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.455);
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.submit {
    background-color: rgba(19, 225, 132, 0.625);
    font-size: x-large;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    border: none;
}

.submit:hover {
    background-color: rgba(19, 225, 132, 1);
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.cat {
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.total {
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: 1000;
}

.count2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
}

.num {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(25, 101, 233);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.num:focus {
    font-size: large;
}

.color {
    width: min-content;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.color:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

.reset {
    background-color: rgb(240, 12, 12);
    color: white;
    font-size: 25pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.reset:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 45pt;
}

.resetduring {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You're only getting the value of the `int1` cookie, you can't use that to set both `onetotal` and `twototal`. You need to set `twototal` from the `int2` cookie.

Comment: @Barmar Could you please explain how I could do this? Should I just duplicate the line in the saveCookie function and edit to only have the other value? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Or you could write a general-purpose function to get a cookie value by name, and use that to set both variables.